# Multi-line labels position and guideline

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I'm trying to indicate a specific point to fixate 2 lines of a feature's labels. This points should by linked to the END of a guideline's position, who is rendered by the "Geometry Generator" in my shapefile.

I already have an example of what is expected as final result in QGIS. It's a dynamic block that I've elaborated several years ago to AutoCAD.

[image: Dynamic block made into AutoCAD.]

Currently what I´ve reached in QGIS, using a Multi-line label and a guideline:

[image: Currently in QGIS]

So, the difference between the 2 examples above is on the 1st and the 4th line of QGIS's labels. As I've said, I want to put it always in the guideline's end point with the 4th line on the closest point and the 1st line after the 4th. The problem is: this place is exactly between the 2nd and 3rd line and if I use one more '\ n' (breakline) the final result is not that good.

I don't know if is that a way to "print" the labels in a specific coordinate using Geometry Generator's expression.

Anyone has another idea to do it with the final result similar to the AutoCAD's block ?

Here's the link with the shapefile and the ".qml" style that I'm using on the GIF's example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12zYPu4aGMMCpXGpE3-mLIiT-q8WM4oae

Label's code:

```
  "Nodo_tipo"    ||   '\n'  || 
  'CT = '  || "CT_(N)"   ||  '\n'   ||  
   'CF = '  ||"CF_nodo"   ||   '\n'  || 
   'h = '  ||"h_nodo_NT"   || 'm'
```

And guideline's generator code:

```
CASE
WHEN @map_scale < 6000
THEN

If ($x < "LABEL_X",

make_line (
make_point( "LABEL_X" + (0.015 * @map_scale), "LABEL_Y" + (0.0065 * 
@map_scale)),
make_point( "LABEL_X" - (0.0020 * @map_scale), "LABEL_Y" + (0.0065 * 
@map_scale)),
make_point( x(centroid( $geometry )), y(centroid( $geometry )))
 ),

make_line (
make_point( "LABEL_X" - (0.0020 * @map_scale), "LABEL_Y" + (0.0065 * 
@map_scale)),
make_point( "LABEL_X" + (0.015 * @map_scale), "LABEL_Y" + (0.0065 * 
@map_scale)),
make_point( x(centroid( $geometry )), y(centroid( $geometry )))

) 

) 
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was working with a rule-based label. In this way you can assign different X, Y positions for each set of labels.

I also made some changes to the guideline generation code.

---

UPDATE: Here's the link with the shapefile and the "line_double_label.qml" style that I'm using on the GIF's example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DsWDSiLuIw9Kf-9gJQv0lUo3dWRvQnA2/view?usp=sharing

---

See the result, very similar to the CAD result.

[image: QGIS LABEL]

[image]

The first label shows the "Nodo_Tipo" and "h_nodo_NT".
The second shows "CT" and "CF".

First label code:

```
If ($x < "LABEL_X", "h_nodo_NT"   || 'm'||'  '||Nodo_tipo
,Nodo_tipo||'  '||"h_nodo_NT"   || 'm')
```

Code for the X and Y coordinates of the label:

X

```
If ($x < "LABEL_X",

"LABEL_X" + (0.02 * @map_scale),
 "LABEL_X" - (0.03 * @map_scale) )
```

Y

```
"LABEL_Y" + (0.0062 *@map_scale)
```

Second label code:

'CT = '  || "CT_(N)"   ||  '\n'   ||
   'CF = '  ||"CF_nodo"   ||   '\n'

Code for the X and Y coordinates of the label:

X

```
"LABEL_X"
```

Y

```
"LABEL_Y"
```

Comment: Narcélio, thanks for the answer it's working exactly like I was seeking